# Points (coordinates) with equal distances from each other on a polygon boundary - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was thinking about a solution for the following problem: How to find X points (coordinates) that have equal distances from each other on a polygon boundary (polyshape object.). I do not know even how to approach it so any ideas how to do it are welcome?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
 
numOfSegments = 10; % just an example
polygon = polyshape([0 5 15 15 20 18 10 20 20],[1 5 10 10 10 15 10 25 35]);
plot(polygon)
P = perimeter(polygon);
SegemntP = P/numOfSegments;
```

Comment: What kind of distance? Along the polygon, or Euclidean?

Comment: Thanks. Along the polygon was my initial idea,but without been greedy also Euclidean will be interesting to see and compare.

Comment: Along the polygon is fairly easy: get the length of the polygon, divide it by the number of points, then place a point at equal distances. The other one is not at all easy, and maybe requires exhaustive search.

Comment: Thanks, I added the sum of the lengths of its boundaries (perimeter) and divided it by the numOfSegments. How I proceed from here to place a point at equal distances?

Answer (score 1):

0. set LengthToGo to `SegemntP`
1. Pick a starting point on your polyshape
2. Move your LengthToGo towards the next point
3. If you don't reach this point, you have found one of your points. Use this as your new starting point and continue with 0.
4. If you have reached this point, reduce LengthToGo by the distance of your starting point and the point you have reached. Set the point you reached to be your new starting point. continue with 0

Hope the following code explains:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
 
numOfSegments = 10; % just an example
polygon = polyshape([0 5 15 15 20 18 10 20 20],[1 5 10 10 10 15 10 25 35]);
% polygon = polyshape([0 20 20 0 0],[0 0 20 20 0]);
plot(polygon)
hold on;

P = perimeter(polygon);
SegemntP = P/numOfSegments;

% this is first point on the polygon
lastPoint = polygon.Vertices(1,:);
% container for points
points = lastPoint;

polyIdx = 1;
lenToGo = SegemntP;
plygonPoints = [polygon.Vertices;polygon.Vertices(1,:)];% add first point so polygon is closed
while(size(points,1)<numOfSegments)
    lenOnPolyline = norm(plygonPoints(polyIdx+1,:)-lastPoint);
    if lenOnPolyline > lenToGo
        % move on this line
        dir = plygonPoints(polyIdx+1,:)-lastPoint;
        dir = dir ./ norm(dir);
        lastPoint = dir*lenToGo+lastPoint;
        points = [points;lastPoint];
        lenToGo = SegemntP;
    else
        % go to next line segment
        lenToGo = lenToGo-lenOnPolyline;
        polyIdx = polyIdx +1;
        lastPoint = plygonPoints(polyIdx,:);
    end
end

plot(points(:,1),points(:,2),'b*')
axis equal
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Very cool. How can I set that the starting point will always be the most left point of the polygon? and how can I numerate each point?

Comment: I added `str = 1:numOfSegments;`
`text(points(:,1)+.5,points(:,2)+.5,string(str));`